# How to get data from date

Tags: sql

Hi I would like to get data from date for users. I ve got a table with all months but i would like to get how much they earn on month

| user | month | money |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | january | 10 |
| 2 | january | 1 |
| 1 | april | 100 |
| 2 | april | 1000 |
| 1 | march | 0 |
| 2 | march | 1 |

And result should be:

| user | money_on_april | money_on_march |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | 1000 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Don't waste people's time writing answers for "wrong" dbms...)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a column for every month, or a certain subset of months:

```
SELECT
    user,
    SUM(CASE month WHEN 'january' THEN money ELSE 0 END) As money_on_january,
    SUM(CASE month WHEN 'february' THEN money ELSE 0 END) As money_on_february,
    ...
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    user
```

If you only want columns for the months which exist in the table, then you'll need to use dynamic SQL instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL, Try PIVOT

```
SELECT * FROM [Your Table]
PIVOT(
SUM([money])
FOR [month] IN ([january],[april],[march])
)pvt
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.